# How to monitor running data extracts?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've create a Data extract Activity and started it; got message "Successfully started the data extract(s)". Now according to documentations, the extracted data file should be present at "export" folder for the Enhanced FTP site. But to my dismay, the file is not getting generated there and I do not have a clue why.

Do we have a way to monitor Data extracts or some logs to view so that I may track what is going on and why the file is not getting extracted?

Site I am checking: ftp://ftp1.exacttarget.com

[image: imgur.com/9EVwRg4] and [image]

Answer (score 1):

Data extracts place files into a staging server once completed. After placed on the staging server, you have to then use a [file transfer activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/file_transfer_activity/) to move the file from the staging server to your Enhanced FTP server.

You will want this activity to be set to download, and the file name should match the expected data extract file name.

Run the data extract activity and file transfer activity as an automation, with the first step as the extract, and on completion, run the file transfer.

When you define a data extract, you choose the events you want to extract. The application creates a separate CSV file for each event and includes them together in the ZIP file.

Your naming pattern for multiple files, should end with `.zip` and not `.csv` for multiple data types selected.

Comment: I tried that, but to no avail. I do not see file in Export folder. Below are the screenshots for the FTP activity and data extract activity I've created... http://imgur.com/9EVwRg4 and http://imgur.com/6nRaSqi

Comment: It ends up in the imports folder.

Comment: Just checked, not present there either. Any logs that may provide me a clue or monitor to tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Edit your question with screen shots of how things are set up.  May be something there

Comment: Added 2. Any specific area you wanted to see?

Comment: You have `Sends.csv` and `sends.csv`.  Try changing those to match.  Also - it helps to run these as an automation in two steps - so you know the extract is completed, and then move the file immediately after completion - it may be trying the transfer a file that's not existing yet.

Comment: I created a program with 2 steps. Step 1 for data extract and step 2 for FTP. Every time It fails at step 2; not sure why. I could think of a few reason of this failure, but can't pin point which one. 1) In data extract Activity, I've ticket "Extract Clicks", and "Extract Sent jobs". If that creates 2 files, then both should be zipped. but the filename I've provided for FTP is sends.csv and not send.zip

Comment: 2) The File location I am using is "ExactTarget Enhanced FTP Site Import Directory". Should it be "ExactTarget Enhanced FTP Site Export Directory"

Comment: If you are zipping the files,  the resulting file will be zip no csv.  It fails on step two because it came find the file.

Comment: I am not zipping any file while data extract. I was just wondering if I select "Extract Clicks" and "extract Sents", the 2 files will be generated.. just a thought on probably issue; we don't have any logs to be sure, right ?

Comment: Actually,  that is exactly the issue...  The file get zipped together. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That's what I thought could be the issue. So I just selected CLiks data and tried again. FTP failed again.

Comment: Would you mind sending your MID to me at kandrews@exacttarget.com. I'll have someone take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Added for Kelly:

1. Data extracts place files into a staging server once completed.
   After placed on the staging server, you have to then use a file
   transfer activity to move the file from the staging server to your
   Enhanced FTP server.
2. And if you plan to extract multiple type of data, make sure the extract file pattern is a *.zip format.
3. For the file transfer activity, choose upload type, source should be enhanced FTP and file name pattern should be the same of data extract.
4. After above two steps are executed successfully, you will find the file on enhance FTP import folder.

Answer (score 0):

In My case I have several BU's and for the BU where I was trying export the file the FTP account **password expired** and It was the error.

From Setup:
I updated the Password for FTP account and the automation start working