# Store Data from Salesforce Marketing Cloud to my local SQL database server

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, sqlserver

Am new to using Marketing Cloud. I want to know if there is a possibility of storing the data from Marketing cloud campaigns and Subscriber activity, Conversion tracking data to my local SQL server?

I have seen people discussing about synchronizing the data from SQL Database into marketing cloud. But I am looking for something the other way, from Marketing cloud into SQL database.

Can someone please guide me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**Tracking Data Extracts**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/extract_types_reference/) and FTP them wherever you need.

The result of these extracts is a ZIP file that contains individual files for each of the options (e.g. Sent.txt, SendJobs.txt) for the date range you've configured.  Whatever process on your side is consuming these files will need to unzip to a temporary directory and import.

Here are the extract API options and my personal categorization.  The documentation (and in SFMC) doesn't really spell out what goes with what.

**Output File Options**

- OutputFileName
- Format
- FileFormat
- QuoteText
- TextQualifier
- ColumnDelimiter
- FileTransferLocation
- UnicodeOutput
- CharacterEncoding

**Notifications**

- NotificationEmail

**Date Options**

- StartDate
- EndDate
- Timezone
- UseLocalTZinQuerypublic
- IncludeMilliseconds

**Qualifiers**

- AccountIDs
- Attributes
- SendIDs
- EmailSendDefinitionExternalKey

**Subscribers**

- ExtractSubscribers
- IncludeAllSubscribers
- ExtractAttributes
- extractStatusChanges

**Send Job**

- ExtractSendJobs
- ExtractSendJobImpressions

**Sent**

- ExtractSent
- ExtractNotSent
- ExtractSendData
- ExtractSendImpressions
- IncludeTestSends
- IncludeCampaignID

**Opens**

- ExtractOpens
- IncludeUniqueOpens
- IncludeInferredOpens
- IncludeGEO
- IncludeUserAgentInformation

**Clicks**

- ExtractClicks
- ExtractClickImpressions
- IncludeUniqueClicks
- IncludeUniqueForURLClicks

**Bounces**

- ExtractBounces

**Unsubscribes**

- ExtractUnsubs
- IncludeUnsubReason
- ExtractSpamComplaints

**Lists and Data Extensions**

- extractListMembershipChanges
- extractLists
- IncludeAllListMembers
- ExtractMultipleDataExtensionListData

**Conversions and Surveys**

- ExtractConversions
- ExtractSurveyResponses

If you kick these extracts off via API, you can specify whatever date range you need -- outside of the bounds of the interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam. I will dwell into details. But if you have done it already and if you have some kind of Extraction steps, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Adam..... Your response and this post has helped me to download the data to my local system https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32368/how-to-monitor-running-data-extracts