# How far back can we make a query?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I'm trying to get all the historical data for a business unit that should go back to 2014, but my queries for Bounces, Sends, Opens, and Clicks only goes back to about 6 months whereas my Jobs query goes back to 2014.  I have no date clause in the queries.

Comment: Please post your queries here

Comment: Was history tracking enabled on that object at that given year you are trying to query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erik, I'm assuming you're talking about Data Views in Marketing Cloud. The documentation clearly states that you can only retrieve up to 6 months' data from the Data View. It's expected that you run your queries monthly and download it or send it to an external database.

You can check with Marketing Cloud Support or your Account Executive to check if they can extract some information from the backend to share with you. It's a long shot but know that queries won't get you the data you're looking for.

For details, refer here:

- [Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the entirety of the activity data using Tracking Data Extracts and either load it in an external database or import it back into SFMC.

If you submit the extract request(s) via SOAP API, then you can specify whatever data range suits your requirements.

The available data is outlined in [**this post**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/169563/5202).

Answer (score 0):

Rajdeep is correct, the data views only go back 6 months. It is worth noting that if Support cannot/will not get you the historic data, it is available via the API. For example, any open events can be pulled via the object below.

- [OpenEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/openevent.htm)